# Validate email address having issue in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
    <button type="submit"
                      class="register-button"
                      :class="(isDisabled) ? '' : 'selected'"
                      :disabled='isDisabled'
                      v-on:click=" isFirstScreen"
                      @click="persist" >
                      PROCEED
   </button>
```

```js
email:'',
maxemail:30,
 
   validationStatus: function (validation) {
      return typeof validation != "undefined" ? validation.$error : false;
    },
    
 computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){

      return (this.fullname  <= this.max) || (this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile)
      || (this.gstin.length < this.maxgstin) ||
       (this.email <= this.maxemail) || !this.terms || !(this.verified == true );
     
}

    isEmail(e) {

      if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(value))
      {
        this.msg['email'] = '';
      } else{
        this.msg['email'] = 'Invalid Email Address';
      } 
    
      
    },
```

```html
 <input
                      type="email"
                      v-model.trim="$v.email.$model"
                      v-validate="'required'"
                      :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.email) }"
                      name="email"
                      class=" input-section"
                      placeholder="Enter your company email ID"
                      :maxlength="maxemail"
                      v-on:keypress="isEmail($event)"
                       id='email'  v-model='email'
                    />
   <div v-if="!$v.email.required" class="invalid-feedback">
                      The email field is required.
                    </div>
                 
                    <div v-if="!$v.email.maxLength" class="invalid-feedback-register">
                       30 characters only
                      {{ $v.user.password.$params.maxLength.min }} 
                    </div>
```

Currently i am unable to validate the email address, even if i enter 2 or 3 characters button is enabling and moving to next page. I want to disable button until user enter valid email address.
Can some one help me on this, to solve the issue for the above code.
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/08/27/vue-js-form-handling-vuelidate/

Comment: Can you checkout link for vuelidate email address, required, minLength,  https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue-vuex-vuelidate-i18n-registration-login-todo/blob/master/src/modules/register/index.vue

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions just to get more answers. There are other ways to get your question attention, including posting a bounty. See [*What should I do if no one answers my question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps it will help you to fix the issue.

Step 1: Install vuelidate using `npm install --save vuelidate`

Step 2: Register vuelidate in `main.js`

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
```

Step 3: Import`required, email, minLength, sameAs` from `vuelidate/lib/validators`

```
import { required, email, minLength, sameAs } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
```

Step 4: Add validations

```
validations: {
 user: {
    name: { required },
    email: { required, email },
    password: { required, minLength: minLength(6) },
    confirmPassword: { required, sameAsPassword: sameAs('password') }
  }
},
```

Step 4: Do the validation on button click

```
methods: {
 submitRegistration () {
   this.submitted = true
   this.$v.$touch()
   if (this.$v.$invalid) {
     return false // stop here if form is invalid
   } else {
     alert('Form Valid')
   }
  }
}
```

Step 5: Design html template

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitRegistration" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="" v-model="user.name" />
        <div v-if="this.submitted && !$v.user.name.required" class="invalid-feedback left">Enter Username</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your company email ID" value="" v-model="user.email" autocomplete="off"/>
        <div v-if="this.submitted && $v.user.email.$error" class="invalid-feedback left">
          <span v-if="!$v.user.email.required">Email is required</span>
          <span v-if="user.email && !$v.user.email.email">Enter valid email address</span>
          <span v-if="user.email && $v.user.email.email && !$v.user.email.maxLength">Email is allowed only 30 characters</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" value="" v-model="user.password" autocomplete="off" />
        <div v-if="this.submitted && $v.user.password.$error" class="invalid-feedback left">
          <span v-if="!$v.user.password.required">Password is required</span>
          <span v-if="user.password && !$v.user.password.minLength">Password must be minimum 6 characters</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Confirm Password" value="" v-model="user.confirmPassword" autocomplete="off" />
        <div v-if="this.submitted && $v.user.confirmPassword.$error" class="invalid-feedback left">
          <span v-if="!$v.user.confirmPassword.required">Confirm Password is required</span>
          <span v-if="user.confirmPassword && !$v.user.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword">Password and Confirm Password should match</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btnRegister" value="Register" :disabled="this.isDisabled" />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Step 6: Button disabled till the form is valid

```
created () {
  this.submitted = true
  return this.$v.$touch()
},
computed: {
  isDisabled () {
    return this.$v.$invalid
  }
},
```

You can refer for demo https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue-vuex-vuelidate-i18n-registration-login-todo

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but issue for my above code is i have isDisabled for button. And in the computed property i need to set condition for isDisabled as to check for @ symbol.com

Comment: For now i have condition in isDisabled is  "(this.email <= this.maxemail)". This condition is only checking for atleast one character move to next screen

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay I updated my answer. Button is disabled till the form is valid.

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay For demo i creaded codesandbox. Hopefully it will helps you. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-goldberg-2mny3